# Good fluid UI for an ASP.NET website or cloud service?

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, cloud, fluid-layout

I'm about to start a new project that is gonna be a composition of a LOB and a cloud-service.

I was thinking about Silverlight, but it looks like a dead technology to me, besides it requires a plugin.

I like the design of Windows-Azure, and I was wondering if there are any well-known and efficient methods I should be aware of before starting out a Fluid-UI that is totally user responsive.

Comment: get well acquainted with CSS ...

Comment: @Xander I'm basically looking for existing resources libraries that will help me get a working sample quickly.

Comment: I actually looked a little into the code, looks like they developed a jQuery library for the whole thingy. I wish there would be an open-sourced lib like this. I'm looking for a Silverlight replacement, I want to use as less JS as possible, using C# instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of them... most notable are Twitter Bootstrap ([twitter.github.com/bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)) and Foundation ([foundation.zurb.com](http://foundation.zurb.com/)).
Both allow easy fluid layouts and come with bundles of extra features and components that you can use!

HTML 5 and Javascript are a safe bet when it comes to UI at the moment, I would avoid plugins like Silverlight as I presume the point of making your UI fluid is the cross device aspect which is kind of defunked immediately with plugins like Flash and Silverlight.

Comment: Thanks! Great stuff. I never know about them OMG.

Comment: No problem... My life has been made much easier since using them. :) Enjoy.

Comment: Do you know of any tools that are optimized for MVC (via Nuget etc.), SO I call it from the views?

Comment: Bootstrap is available via Nuget... to be honest though, they are simply CSS and Javascript files that you include in your pages and then make sure of their pre-defined classes and functions... None of them are going to require any references to DLL's or anything, they are completely platform agnostic.

Comment: Is it free for commercial use? Under what conditions, I'm not a law guy and the licences are really gibberish to me.

Comment: It is free for commercial use.